# typedef template, is this one possible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

Is it possible to do something like:

```
template< typename T >
using T_CCUnit = static const constexpr T;
```

In fact i just want an alias for `static const constexpr`, because it's really boring to write everytime in some file.
I'll prefer a solution in c++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add const-ness to the type easily enough, because cv-qualifiers modify the type:

```
template <typename T>
using T_C = std::add_const_t<T>;
```

However, `static` and `constexpr` modify declarations, rather than types. So, here:

```
                         int x1;
                   const int x2;
  static           const int x3;
  static constexpr const int x4;
//      |    ^    |  type   |name
//   ^  | constexpr specifier
// storage class specifier
```

the last three declarations are all of type `const int`, but `x2` has different storage class to `x3` and `x4`.

Honestly, if the main problem is that

> ... it's really boring to write ...

my best suggestion is that you learn how to write macros or save common code snippets in your preferred editor.

Comment: I'll stay on macro like teivaz said. Thanks for the details! Snippets won't do it, because i'm making a lot of flag declaration, and it will be a mess with all these keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you will be to use macro for that.

`#define STATIC_CONST_CONSTEXPR static const constexpr`

But seriously, `static` and `constexpr` are not modifiers for the type. All you can do with `using` in your case is `const T`. Everything else you either write yourself or ask preprocessor to write for you.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was so focus to found a "c++" method that i forgot the simpliest one : macro.
I'll wait a little if somebody have another idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` storage qualifier applies to instances, not types. So it's impossible to `typedef` it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot typedef `static` or `constexpr` - neither are part of the type. That said, even if you could, nobody will know what:

```
T_CCUnit<int> x = 4;
```

means, but everybody will know what:

```
static constexpr int x = 4;
```

means. It is worth typing an extra 7 characters every time to make your code more legible. All readers of your code, and your future self, will thank you.

---

Side-note, `const` is redundant with `constexpr` - every variable declared `constexpr` is implicitly `const`.

Comment: I know i spoke about c++11, but constexpr is no more const in c++14. So if i can move on c++14, i'll have some problem.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel "A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`." [\[dcl.constexpr\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#9)

Comment: Oh seems you're right about static member, the clause speak only about non-static member. A little strange but why not, i'll try it, thanks.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel The phrase I cited speaks about objects, not about members. Non-static data members can't be `constexpr`.

Comment: Sorry i missed a word in my comment, the clause speak about functions. I need to check more about c++14...

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel No, the paragraph cited is about objects, not functions.

Comment: Yes that's why i said you're right. The clause i remembered was only for non-static function member.